# How to get my simple Node.js socket application working in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My experience with sockets have generally been to run a server in a terminal, set up a client in another terminal, and watch them interact with each other.

I found a very basic Node.js socket application tutorial as pictured. The client auto generates numbers, and sends them to the client to echo back.

It is my first time using Elastic Beanstalk. I managed to get past all of the other issues I was having, and now it is launching the url.
My server.js/client.js/app.js isn't printing to the Console using the developer tools (F12), and I am wondering why (you can see in my code I have put very blatant console logs). Sources also only shows the index.jade file (not server.js, client.js etc)

I am also relatively new to Node.js.

What I want to do is simulate/run my client so it will interact with the server that is now on Beanstalk. I want the client to generate its numbers, and for the server to print it to the console (in the browser). 
It works fine locally. I hope I have made my issue clear.

I thought maybe it is because I am not forcing client to launch somewhere in my code. However, as you can see in package.json, I am telling server.js to start (and server.js won't print to console in the browser, even though there are plenty of console.logs in there).

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
//var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
console.log("HI IM IN APP.JS");

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8081);

app.listen(8081);

module.exports = app;
```

**client.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var WebSocketClient = require('websocket').client;

var client = new WebSocketClient();
console.log("HELLO I AM YOUR CLIENT :D");

client.on('connectFailed', function(error) {
    console.log('Connect Error: ' + error.toString());
});

client.on('connect', function(connection) {
    console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
    connection.on('error', function(error) {
        console.log("Connection Error: " + error.toString());
    });
    connection.on('close', function() {
        console.log('echo-protocol Connection Closed');
    });
    connection.on('message', function(message) {
        if (message.type === 'utf8') {
            console.log("Received: '" + message.utf8Data + "'");
        }
    });

    function sendNumber() {
        if (connection.connected) {
            var number = Math.round(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF);
            connection.sendUTF(number.toString());
            setTimeout(sendNumber, 1000);
        }
    }
    sendNumber();
});

client.connect('ws://localhost:8081/', 'echo-protocol');
```

**server.js**

```
var WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Received request for ' + request.url);
    response.writeHead(404);
    response.end();
});
server.listen(8081, function() {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Server is listening on port 8081');
});

console.log("HELLO I AM HERE. I'M YOUR SERVER :D");



wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: server,
    // You should not use autoAcceptConnections for production
    // applications, as it defeats all standard cross-origin protection
    // facilities built into the protocol and the browser.  You should
    // *always* verify the connection's origin and decide whether or not
    // to accept it.
    autoAcceptConnections: false
});

function originIsAllowed(origin) {
    // put logic here to detect whether the specified origin is allowed.
    return true;
}

wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
    if (!originIsAllowed(request.origin)) {
        // Make sure we only accept requests from an allowed origin
        request.reject();
        console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection from origin ' + request.origin + ' rejected.');
        return;
    }

    var connection = request.accept('echo-protocol', request.origin);
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection accepted.');
    connection.on('message', function(message) {
        if (message.type === 'utf8') {
            console.log('Received Message: ' + message.utf8Data);
            connection.sendUTF(message.utf8Data);
        }
        else if (message.type === 'binary') {
            console.log('Received Binary Message of ' + message.binaryData.length + ' bytes');
            connection.sendBytes(message.binaryData);
        }
    });
    connection.on('close', function(reasonCode, description) {
        console.log((new Date()) + ' Peer ' + connection.remoteAddress + ' disconnected.');
    });
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "nodewebsockets",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.18.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.15.5",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.4.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you allowing port 8081 through on your AWS security group?

Comment: @stdunbar I had made an IAM user that I have given full auth of EC2. The webpage launces the basic index.jade file that will say in the browser (Express. Welcome to Express). Is this what you mean? Until I changed the ports in my application to 8081, it wouldn't be connect to beanstalk.

Comment: However, you did bring my attention to the eb logs.

"2017/12/14 01:22:36 [error] 4787#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.21.80, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/", host: "help-dev.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"
"